# Inplace rotation of a matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix

I have a list of lists (which I am calling here matrix), that I want to rotate by 90 clockwise in-place (i.e., without coping into another matrix). I came up with the following code.

I am interested in the algorithm itself, in a pure python (without transposing using numpy or so).

```
def rotate(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = len(M[0])

    for i in range(n//2):
        for j in range(i, m-1-i):
            ii, jj = i, j
            v0 = M[ii][jj]
            for _ in range(3):
                M[ii][jj] = M[n-1-jj][ii]
                ii, jj = n-1-jj, ii
            M[ii][jj] = v0

    return M
```

It works well but only when the number of lines is equal to the number of columns. Any ideas for modifying my function to handle the case where the number of lines and columns are not equal ?

Here is an example :

```
input:      [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
            [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

output      [[21, 16, 11, 6, 1],
            [22, 17, 12, 7, 2],
            [23, 18, 13, 8, 3],
            [24, 19, 14, 9, 4],
            [25, 20, 15, 10, 5]]
```

Comment: Why don't you take a transpose and re-order columns? Also, use `numpy`

Comment: @martianwars I am more interested in the algorithm itself, in a pure python (without transposing by using numpy etc).

Comment: There's no way of inplace-rotating a `N x  M`-matrix with `N != M`, simply because the in- and output-matrices differ in size (`N x M` vs `M x N`).

Comment: You would need to use at least some temp variable.

Comment: All right, don't use numpy, but what's wrong with transpose?

Comment: @martianwars nothing wrong with it, I just want to do it "in-place" (without creating an alternative matrix or lists ..)

Comment: As @Paul mentioned, it can't be in-place, unless its a squared 2D array. Is it so?

Comment: If storage is a concern, you can emulate the behavior using the function i've written in my answer

Comment: A non numpy version is: `[list(row[::-1]) for row in zip(*M)]`.   `M` does not have to be 'square'.  But it does make a new list of lists.

Comment: Your in-place code is slower than the suggested alternatives. In a Python/numpy world in-place does not save time.  At best it reduces MemoryErrors for extremely large data sets.

Comment: @hpaulj the in-place version is intended to save memory for very large matrix, while it is still within the same runtime complexity as the numpy version.

Comment: I don't know what `runtime complexity` means, especially if comparing list operations with numpy ones.

Comment: @hpaulj it is the time complexity in terms of the big O notation.

Comment: Your code does scale with an O2 for side dimension.  But I have to increase the sides to 10000 to start seeing time increases for the array operations.  Your `rotate` does noticeably better on lists of lists than on arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `numpy` for matrix operations. I'll  assume an `m*n` numpy array `arr`. I first did a transpose using the [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) function and then I flipped it using the [`np.fliplr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) function.

```
output = np.fliplr(np.transpose(arr))
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to do an in-place replace without a temporary variable for rectangular matrices. It's better to simulate the behavior (if storage is your concern) using a function like this,

```
def clockwise(matrix, row, column):
    return matrix[-(column + 1)][row]
```

Comment: I edited the question, as I said in comments: I am more interested in the algorithm itself, in a pure python (without transposing using numpy or so).

Comment: @eLearner So what stops you from just implementing the left-right flip and transposition on your own? It's just a more compact version of the algorithm you asked for...

Answer (score 3):

To rotate a 2-D matrix by 90 clockwise in-place(without allocated new matrix), it will include two steps as follows.

1. Inverse rows in matrix
2. Transpose the whole matrix

```py
"""Example:
[                 [                [
[1,2,3],          [7,8,9]          [7,4,1]
[4,5,6],    ->    [4,5,6]    ->    [8,5,2]
[7,8,9]           [1,2,3]          [9,6,3]
]                 ]                ]
"""
def rotate(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    columns = len(matrix[0])
        
    # inverse row
    for i in range(rows//2):
        matrix[i], matrix[columns-i-1] =\
        matrix[columns-i-1], matrix[i]
        
    # transpose
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] =\
            matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    rotate(matrix)
    print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

[martianwars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41290406/240490) is great. There is a more direct route with NumPy, however:

```
np.rot90(arr)
```

The only fly in the ointment is that [rot90](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) rotates the array *counterclockwise* whereas the OP's example seemed to want clockwise. No problem, though. There's a parameter `k` for how many rotates to (logically) perform. For `i` clockwise rotates:

```
np.rot90(arr, 4-i)
```

Comment: If you are still on a computer, could you benchmark this and compare it with the solution I provided or larger matrices? I just read about this too!

Comment: I don't know how it is implemented, but if I call `np.rot90(arr, k=3)` would it actually rotate it once by 270 degree, or would it rotate it 3 times (i.e. 3 nested calls to `np.rot90(arr)`) which will be then more time consuming ?

Comment: `rot90` is not more direct; it just hides the calls to `fliplr` and `transpose`.  And `fliplr` is just an reverse slice: `m[:, ::-1]`.

Comment: "Direct" means "without intervening factors or intermediaries." A single call to a rotation API is therefore inherently more direct than multiple composed calls, list comprehensions, or other approaches. That a subtask of rotation is equivalent to slicing notation is interesting but immaterial. It's still the long way around.

Comment: `rot90` is python, not compiled.  My python code can be just as fast.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have rightly suggested `rot90` or `transpose` and `fliplr`.  If you dig into their code, you see that the action can be reduced to a `transpose` and a reverse indexing:

```
In [467]: arr=np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
In [468]: arr.transpose()
Out[468]: 
array([[ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21],
       [ 2,  7, 12, 17, 22],
       [ 3,  8, 13, 18, 23],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24],
       [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]])
In [469]: arr.transpose()[:,::-1]
Out[469]: 
array([[21, 16, 11,  6,  1],
       [22, 17, 12,  7,  2],
       [23, 18, 13,  8,  3],
       [24, 19, 14,  9,  4],
       [25, 20, 15, 10,  5]])
```

Individually `transpose` and `[:,::-1]` produce views.  That is, the array is new, but it shares a data buffer with the original.  But together, `numpy` has to make a copy.  In other words, you can't get the numbers `[21, 16, 11,...]` from `[1,2,3,...]` without reordering them.

Both `transpose` and `[::-1]` indexing are implemented in compiled code.  `transpose` is actually a 'superficial' action, changing array `shape` and `strides` (and `order`), but not rearranging any values.  By itself, `[:,::-1]` be a `strides` change, but with the `order` change it also has to perform an array copy.

### The gory details

```
In [470]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[470]: 
{'data': (151576248, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (5, 5),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [471]: arr1 = arr.transpose()
In [472]: arr1.__array_interface__
Out[472]: 
{'data': (151576248, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (5, 5),
 'strides': (4, 20),
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [473]: arr2 = arr1.copy()
In [474]: arr2.__array_interface__
Out[474]: 
{'data': (154237272, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (5, 5),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [475]: arr3 = arr2[:,::-1]
In [476]: arr3.__array_interface__
Out[476]: 
{'data': (154237288, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (5, 5),
 'strides': (20, -4),   # or (4,-20) without the explicit copy()
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

### A list version

Here's a `pure Python` list implementation.  `zip(*)` is a list version of transpose.  And `[::-1]` reverses lists just as it does arrays.

```
In [479]: alist1=arr.tolist()
In [480]: alist1
Out[480]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
In [481]: alist2=list(zip(*alist1))
In [482]: alist2
Out[482]: 
[(1, 6, 11, 16, 21),
 (2, 7, 12, 17, 22),
 (3, 8, 13, 18, 23),
 (4, 9, 14, 19, 24),
 (5, 10, 15, 20, 25)]
In [483]: alist3=[l[::-1] for l in alist2]
In [484]: alist3
Out[484]: 
[(21, 16, 11, 6, 1),
 (22, 17, 12, 7, 2),
 (23, 18, 13, 8, 3),
 (24, 19, 14, 9, 4),
 (25, 20, 15, 10, 5)]
```

or in one line:

```
[list(l[::-1]) for l in zip(*alist1)]
```

That inner `list` is needed to make a list of lists rather than list of tuples.

This `list` code works if the 'matrix' is not square.  But it is making a number of copies of the lists along the way.  But that is typical of Python's way with lists.  It is nearly always easier to create a new list from the old (via list comprehensions) than to mutate the original.  Your `rotate` function is proof of that.  I can't tell at a glance what is doing.  You have obscure ranges like `n//2` and `m-1-i`.  And you can't handle the case where `n` and `m` differ (so the resulting outer list has a different length than the original).

Keep in mind that lists contain pointers, not values.  A 'matrix' list is just one list that contains pointers to other lists, which themselves point to values stored else where in memory.

=======================

### Some timings

```
In [493]: %%timeit alist=arr.tolist()
     ...: rotate(alist)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21 µs per loop

In [494]: %%timeit alist=arr.tolist()
     ...: [list(row[::-1]) for row in zip(*alist)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.83 µs per loop
```

the pure array operation is much faster:

```
In [495]: timeit arr.transpose()[:,::-1]
The slowest run took 11.51 times longer....
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 µs per loop
```

but turning a nested list into an array does take time

```
In [496]: %%timeit alist=arr.tolist()
     ...: np.array(alist).transpose()[:,::-1]
     ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop
```

For comparison, the `direct` numpy function - this array is small enough that a couple of layers of function calls chews up a significant amount of time.

```
In [523]: timeit np.rot90(arr,-1)
The slowest run took 5.06 times longer ...
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.18 µs per loop
```

I imagine that with bigger arrays, the `in-place` `rotate` will get relatively worse - until the others produce `MemoryErrors`.