# Efficient transformations of 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, 3d

I have some 3D numpy arrays that need to be transformed in various ways. E.g.:

```
x.shape = (4, 17, 17)
```

This array is 1 sample of 4 planes, each of size 17x17. What is the most efficient way to transform each plane: flipud, fliplr, and rot90? Is there a better way than using a for loop? Thanks!

```
for p in range(4):
    x[p, :, :] = np.fliplr(x[p, :, :])
```

Comment: could you use an example array and indicate what you want it to look like... eg. a = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code of these functions:

```
def fliplr(...):
   ....
   return m[:, ::-1]
```

In other words it returns a view with reverse slicing on the 2nd dimension

Your `x[p, :, :] = np.fliplr(x[p, :, :]` applies that reverse slicing to the last dimension, so the equivalent for the whole array should be

```
x[:, :, ::-1]
```

flipping the 2nd axis would be

```
x[:, ::-1, :]
```

etc.

`np.rot90` has 4 case (k); for `k=1` it is

```
return fliplr(m).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

in other words `m[:, ::-1].swapaxes(0,1)`

To work on your planes you would do something like

```
m[:, :,::-1].swapaxes(1,2)
```

or you could do the `swapaxes/transpose` first

```
m.transpose(0,2,1)[:, :, ::-1]
```

Does that give you enough tools to transform the plane's in what ever way you want?

As I discussed in another recent question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291462/901925, the `flip...` returns a view, but the `rot90`, with both flip and swap, will, most likely return a copy.  Either way, `numpy` will be giving you the most efficient version.